# How to add matplotlib from python3.6 to Blender?

Tags: python, matplotlib, blender

In Window, I installed python3.6
and, installed matplotlib by commandline:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

After installation, I was running matplotlib in python console,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as plb
```

In python36\lib\site-packages

[image: site-packages]

I want in blender to use the matplotlib library in python, 
Can I copy the matplotlib in `python36\lib\site-packages` of Python into the `Blender\2.78 \python\lib\site-packages`?

I tried copying but only importing matplotlib, but when `import matplotlib.pylot as plt the error is as follows

[image: errors]

I do not know how to fix it, please help me

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/141162/74508
I think I have found the way to use python3.6

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/141162/74508 I think I have found the way to use python3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will want to make sure you use the same python version as blender was built with, for blender 2.78 that is python 3.5. For compiled python modules like matplotlib this is more important than pure python modules.

There are few ways to use third party modules, first like you are trying, is to install them into blender's copy of python. Another way is to delete blender's python so that it uses the system installed version. You can also adjust [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.path) to allow blender's python to find third party modules.

Comment: thank @sambler, i using python 3.6, different blender 2.78

Comment: @hoald, Can you give me more details on how to use system python for blender. I delete the `$PATH/blener.app/Contexts/Resources/2.78/python`, and set `PYTHONPATH` as my system python, say `/usr/local/python3`. But in this situation, I cannot start blender. Thanks. (I use mac sierra, both python versions are 3.5.2)

Comment: @Zhenjie Zhao: you try delete Python folder in Blender, copy python3 folder replace blender/2.78/. Copy python35.dll in python3 to blender/ .